# Webworker not posting message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-worker, webpacker

I can't get a webworker to post a message (using Webpack).

---

**FIRST TRY**

I have a Rails app with an entry point for the webworker, and an entry point for the main thread Javascript.

I'm ONLY using the native WebWorker api here. A separate file is created intended ONLY to be used for the Webworker.

The webworker code is compiled down to it's own file. The file is downloaded without issue. The network tab shows it loads with 200.

```
worker = new Worker(workerUrl);
// url points to the worker's URL
// I get the URL with `asset_pack_url('worker.js')`
// resolves to something like http://localhost:5000/packs/worker-aaa739e5a169b00de74b.js
// I can navigate to this file and see it..
```

The compiled worker file has some Webpacker stuff, but the main part looks like this...
Very simple

```
self.onmessage = function runParser(_e) {
  var x = 'a test value';
  self.postMessage(x); 
};
```

In the main thread..

```
worker = new Worker(workerUrl);

worker.postMessage('test');

worker.onmessage = () => {
  alert('contact made with the other side');
}
```

But no message is sent. The alert never fires. Nothing happens.

---

**SECOND TRY**

According to Webpack docs, no loader is needed..

https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/#root

Also, instead of pointing a WebWorker to a URL, I can point it to a local file.

```
new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));
```

Results in...

```
Security Error: Content at http://localhost:5000/@stoplion/ea-ut-eum-at may not load data from file:///Users/geo/Code/My Project/my-app/app/client/src/workers/worker.
```

Comment: FF says: "_Uncaught TypeError: Worker.postMessage: 0 is not a valid argument count for any overload._" You've to pass at least the message to `postMessage`.

Comment: Even if an argument  is passed nothing happens

Comment: Now after your edit, the worker must be saved on a (local?) server, you can't load a worker anywhere from your local disk using file protocol.

Comment: I'm actually trying both ways. Loading from URL and the directions here https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/#root. I'm guessing for the second one, Webpack is doing something (making it a Blob?). In the first attempt (URL) simply nothing happens, no error, no nothing. In the second try, I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

what webpack loader you use for workers?

try `npm i worker-loader`

it is  better to name worker files with `worker` suffix `filename.worker.js`

with rules like this

```
 rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: [
      /node_modules/,
      /\.worker\.js$/
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.worker\.js$/,
    use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
  }
]
```

with excluding workers from other js file processing

also add error handler, maybe it will return something useful

```
worker.onerror = e => {
  console.error(e);
}
```

and `onmessage` looks strange, try remove self and function name

```
onmessage = function (_e) {
  var x = 'a test value';
  postMessage(x); 
};
```

Comment: I'm not using any loader. I'm using just plain web workers. Webpacker is compiling a separate file for me and I'm loading it up using plain web worker api